# How can I load a Maya .MA file from MEL when it has an unresolved reference?

Tags: maya, mel

I am trying to use a `MEL script` to load `ANIMATION.MA` file that references `CHARACTER_RIG.MA`. The `CHARACTER_RIG.MA` and `ANIMATION.MA` files are produced by someone else and supplied to me. The `ANIMATION.MA` is looking for
 `N:/Project/Maya//char/character/CHARACTER_RIG.MA`

If I open ANIMATION.MA from Maya, or use the equivalent MEL command I always get prompted with:

```
"Reference File Not Found"
Reference File Not Found: N:/Project/Maya//char/character/CHARACTER_RIG.MA.
[Abort File Read] [Skip] [Browse...] [Retry]
```

If I tap browse, and select the `CHARACTER_RIG.MA` then it opens perfectly. I can see it created a reference in the Reference Editor that has the Unresolved Path (N:/...) , the Resolved Path (/my/path) and the namespace and the namespaceRN.

My question is, how do I do the equivalent of the "Browse..." from MEL? I tried pre-creating a reference, but it doesn't let me set the unresolved path, so when I load the ANIMATION.MA it keeps prompting in MAYA.

```
file -f -options "v=0"  -typ "mayaAscii" -o "/Source/project/assets/anims/ANIMATION.MA"
```

Comment: I have found a work-around solution. Since I am using .MA files, which are ASCII, it is simple enough to edit the file directly to change the path to point to the correct CHARACTER_RIG.MA location.

Since I was calling the MEL script from a shell script, I ended up search&replacing the path in the MA file with:

`perl -pi -e 's/\Qold-path\E/\Qnew-path\E/g' ANIMATION.MA`

Hope that helps someone else.

Comment: I found a much simpler solution - involving no code: Maya will also look for a matching filename in the current and project directories. In this case I just copied CHARACTER_RIG.MA in to the same folder as ANIMATION.MA and it loaded it automatically. HTH.(So obvious in hindsight)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding several solutions:

> 1. Rename the RIG.MA file to match the filename in ANIM.MA (they were different in my case) and put it in one of the search or project folders that MAYA uses and it will automatically find it.

or

> 1. Programatically through code (or manually) edit the ANIM.MA file to remap the file/folder of the RIG.MA to where you want to load it from. Note: You
>      also need to remap any other files, such as textures. I did this with
>      `perl -pi -e 's/\Qold-path\E/\Qnew-path\E/g' ANIMATION.MA`

HTH someone else.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the directory where the file is, then you can use the **dirmap** command. The command *dirmap* allows you to remap directory structures if your disk configuration changes. So in this case it would look like:

```
dirmap -en true;
dirmap -m "N:/Project/Maya//char/character" "/my/path";
```

Possibly more manageable if you have lots of mappings to do especially when moving form a windows machine to a *nix one. However it is much more useful to define your project structure because then things just work when you move, tough this may not be the best of choice for shared assets.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and easy, File, Project, Set and select the folder where meshes or whatever it is.